# How can I find the name of the enum class by looking at the test in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a test file, and from reading this test file I should construct the class, this is the test :

```
TEST_CASE("Person1") {
    const char * name   = "Bruce";
    const char * lastname      = "Wayne";
    Person::Gender gender = Person::MAN;
    Person p(name, lastname, gender);

    REQUIRE( name    == p.getName());
    REQUIRE( lastname       == p.getLastName());
    REQUIRE( gender     == p.getGender());
}
```

Gender is an enum ,but I can't find its name, is it Person or Gender or Person::Gender?
If it's Person that it has the same name as the class?

Comment: It probably is called `Gender` and is defined inside of the `class` (or `struct`) `Person`.

Comment: Without the declaration of `Gender`, it is not really possible to know what its fully qualified name is. (See also [mcve].)